# Core Data doesn't store nil over app restart

Tags: ios, core-data

I have 2 objects in Core Data;

CurrentSession, Session

currentSession.session has 1 session, aka;

```
currentSession.session = session; 
[self save]; // which does the context save
```

This all works very well, however, when I do ;

```
currentSession.session = nil; 
[self save];
```

it works well as long as i'm in the running application I did that in. When I restart the application from Xcode and come back in it, currentSession.session suddenly is not nil anymore. It's the value it was before I set it to nil.

I tried running

[[self dataContext] processPendingChanges];

the changes as well with the result. What could be the issue here?

Comment: The save method of NSManagedObjectContext has a return value and an error parameter. Did you check if the save was successful? I'd could e.g. fail due to validation errors.

Comment: My save method looks like     NSError *error;
    if (![dataContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]); => is there anything more I should check in that regard? 
    }

Comment: So you don't get an error when saving? That is strange. You don't by chance create a default database every time the app starts? - You can set the launch argument "-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3" to get debugging output, perhaps that helps.

Comment: No errors. I'll try to add that argument. The weird thing is that when I reload the data in another model in the same app run, all data is fine, just when I restart, all is still fine EXCEPT this nil. I'll my findings here.

Comment: What do you mean by "loading the data in another model"? Do you use multiple managed object contexts?

Comment: I mean that if the app is not restarted, the values, even when reloaded will always yield the correct result, while after restart, they will always yield the wrong result. Sorry for the confusion.